# ValueError: unknown url type: 'LanguageTool-3.2.zip'

Tags: python-3.x, url, pip, nlp, urllib

I am trying to install pycontractions library which is dependent on language-check library. So when installing language-check I am getting the below error

```
ValueError: unknown url type: 'LanguageTool-3.2.zip
```

I have python-3.10 and java-8 installed. When I am using `pip install language-check`, I get `urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden` So, I downloaded language tool manually(as instructed in github link) and run the following command:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/myint/language-check
```

I tried all the possible ways available here but still couldnt resolve it. Its getting installed on mac with no issues but I am a windows user. So I need to install it in my windows desktop.
Error:

```
Collecting git+https://github.com/myint/language-check.git
  Cloning https://github.com/myint/language-check.git to c:\users\skamble\appdata\local\temp\pip-req-build-c78lrf2e
  Running command git clone --filter=blob:none -q https://github.com/myint/language-check.git 'C:\Users\skamble\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-c78lrf2e'
  Resolved https://github.com/myint/language-check.git to commit 58e419833ef28a9193fcaa21193616a8a14504a9
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for language-check, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: language-check
    Running setup.py install for language-check ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\skamble\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\skamble\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-req-build-c78lrf2e\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\skamble\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-req-build-c78lrf2e\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\skamble\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-msctmso8\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\skamble\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Include\language-check'
         cwd: C:\Users\skamble\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-c78lrf2e\
    Complete output (23 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\skamble\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-c78lrf2e\setup.py", line 595, in <module>
        sys.exit(main())
      File "C:\Users\skamble\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-c78lrf2e\setup.py", line 590, in main
        run_setup_hooks(config)
      File "C:\Users\skamble\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-c78lrf2e\setup.py", line 561, in run_setup_hooks
        language_tool_hook(config)
      File "C:\Users\skamble\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-c78lrf2e\setup.py", line 584, in language_tool_hook
        download_lt()
      File "C:\Users\skamble\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-c78lrf2e\download_lt.py", line 131, in download_lt
        with closing(urlopen(url)) as u:
      File "C:\Users\skamble\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\urllib\request.py", line 216, in urlopen
        return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
      File "C:\Users\skamble\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\urllib\request.py", line 503, in open
        req = Request(fullurl, data)
      File "C:\Users\skamble\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\urllib\request.py", line 322, in __init__
        self.full_url = url
      File "C:\Users\skamble\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\urllib\request.py", line 348, in full_url
        self._parse()
      File "C:\Users\skamble\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\urllib\request.py", line 377, in _parse
        raise ValueError("unknown url type: %r" % self.full_url)
    ValueError: unknown url type: 'LanguageTool-3.2.zip'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\skamble\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\skamble\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-req-build-c78lrf2e\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\skamble\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-req-build-c78lrf2e\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\skamble\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-msctmso8\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\skamble\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Include\language-check' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: How are you trying to install this library?  Is there a command you are running to do so?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller updated my question

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it. Used `git+https://github.com/coreyryanhanson/language-check` and it worked.